# Prove by induction: $9\mid (4^{3n} + 8)$ for all integers $n \geq 0$.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I cannot seem to figure this one out.

My though process so far is the following:

$\textit{Proof}$: For the base case n = 0, we have $9 \mid (4^0 + 8)$. This is true.

$\textit{Inductive step:}$ Suppose for $k \geq 0$ we have that $9\mid (4^{3k} + 8)$. We will show that $9 \mid (4^{3(k + 1)} + 8)$. The statement $9 \mid (4^{3k} + 8)$ can be expressed as $4^{3k} + 8 = 9a$ for integer $a$. Observe that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split} 4^{3(k + 1)} + 8 &= 4^{3k}4^3 + 8 \\ &= 
 \dots \\ &\vdots \\ &= 9 (z)\end{split}\end{equation}$$
Where $z$ is some integer. I feel I am forgetting some algebraic properties or a manipulation of the equation above of some sort to help in this prove.

Any help is great! Thanks!

Comment: Well, using the inductive hypothesis, we could assume $4^{3k}+8$=$9a$, i.e., $4^{3k}$=$9a-8$. Then for $k+1$, use this fact about $4^{3k}$, and see what you get. ;)

Comment: Thank you! @toolfan3

Comment: No problem Owen!

Comment: This strategy is also commonly used for induction divisor style proofs such as these, so I recommend you study more problems like this and do substitutions as I have done. (It really helps in the long run)! Happy mathing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4^{3k}+8=9a\to 4^{3k}=9a-8$

$4^{3k+3}+8=4^{3k}\cdot 4^3+8=(9a-8)\cdot 64+8=576 a-504=9(64a-56)=9z$

Comment: Thank you @Raffaele! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Induction is not necessary. What is the order of $2\bmod 8$?

It you really need induction, you can rewrite
\begin{align}
4^{3(k + 1)} + 8&= 4^{3k} \,4^3 + 8\cdot4^3 -8\cdot4^3+8 \\
&=4^3\bigl(4^{3k}+8\bigr)+8(1-4^3).
\end{align}

Comment: I am not familiar with what it means to ask for the order of an integer a mod b where b is an integer.

Comment: It is the order as an element in the multiplicative group $(\mathbf Z/9\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\!\times}$. This being, I've added a hint for the inductive step, but congruences yield a more elegant proof.

Comment: If you're going to skip induction, then $4^3\equiv 1 \bmod 9 \Rightarrow 4^{3n}=(4^3)^n \equiv 1 \bmod 9$ and you're essentially done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we *need* to use $4^{3k} +8$ is divisible by $9$.

SO we have somehow isolate $4^{3k} + 8$ from $4^{3k}4^3 + 8$.

Only way I see to do that is $4^{3k}4^3 + 8= (4^3 - 1)4^{3k} + \color{blue}{(4^{3k} + 8)}$

Now we know $9$ divides $\color{blue}{(4^{3k} + 8)}$ so it suffices to show $9$ divides $(4^3-1)4^{3k}$ as well.

As the only prime factors of $4^{3k}$ is $2$ at suffices to show $9$ divides $4^3-1$.

And that's a single constant value.

> Oh... come on! Did you really need to peek at the spoiler to figure out how to prove $9$ divides into $4^3 -1$?